# How to calculate total score in a palindrome game between two players?

Tags: c++, string, function, parameter-passing, palindrome

My program alternatively prompt two players for a palindrome each then based on its type (sentence, word or digits) assign it a score. it keeps prompting the players for palindromes and calculate and display the total score of each player. The problem is the score is reset every time so program only shows the score from last round not the total score. I need to calculate the total score for each player after every round.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are leaving the method every round, leaving the scores out of scope.

This way, the variables get destroyed and are created again the next round.

You will need to store the scores differently to keep track of the total score or refactor the code so that these variables would never be destroyed. (you would have to move the loop and make other changes)